# Modeling aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have the following requirements:

- There are articles created by admin users
- For each articles there are questions related with the article
- The admin can ask between 1 and 3 questions per article
- And each question can have between 2 and 5 answers
- The question text and answer text can be modified in every moment before article be published
- Finally, the admin publish the article and others users can select an answer for each question about the article.

Well, in this situation, you would create an aggregate for article, other for question and other for answer.

If yes, how to keep the invariant that an article have between 1 and 3 questions?

If no, how would you model it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Article aggregate includes a set of references to Question (via an aggregate root, e.g. the question ID)
- An attempt to add a reference to a Question fails if there are already 3 references for that Article

Since an aggregate defines a consistency boundary, publishing an article is a saga.  Adding a question is likewise going to be a saga if you want the Question to track which Article(s) it's associated with (you didn't directly say that Question maintains an invariant that it's only ever associated with one article).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Would be ok if in article aggregate I include a questions counter instead of set of references to Question aggregate root?

Comment: And if I include in article aggregate the set of references to Question, when I persist the article aggregate, how would you persiste that references?, in a column in article table?, in a separate table?

Comment: You might be able to get away with a counter, but: 1) if you're going to have a query which is "what questions are associated with this article", you should track it and 2) it's likely desirable to allow an attempt to associate a question with an article that's already associated to succeed (since it can't violate the constraint, after all), and a counter doesn't give you that ability.

Comment: DDD tends to only use DBs as document stores (or even just as a blob store with metadata, especially if doing CQRS and even more so if event sourcing): a major reason why is the limitation on accessing aggregates except by their root (aggregates owning enforcement of constraints and their being transaction boundaries also makes DDD exclusive of a lot of benefits of a relational model).  If you were going to represent it relationally, if there's going to be a limited number, then 3 columns would work, otherwise a table with article ID and question ID columns would work.

Comment: And last question, would you keep two separates aggregates question and answer?, or would you include answer entity inside question aggregate?, what rules would you follow to take that decision?

Comment: I would take a similar approach: answer is an aggregate and question maintains a set of references (though the 2 to 5 requirement is interesting: that might suggest modeling a NotYetAnsweredQuestion as a slightly different thing than a Question)